# Is there a term for a function $f$ such that $x f'(x)$ is decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, convex-analysis

Consider a differentiable, monotonically increasing function $f$.

- If $f'(x)$ is increasing, then $f$ is convex.
- If $f'(x)$ is decreasing, then $f$ is concave.

> Is there a term that describes $f$ when $x f'(x)$ is decreasing?

I thought that a good name for such a function can be "mega-concave", since 
the last condition is stronger than concavity. For example, $\sqrt{x}$ is concave but not "mega-concave". $\log{x}$ is mega-concave, while $-1/x^2$ is "strictly mega-concave" ($x f'(x)$ is strictly decreasing).

I have not found this term anywhere. Is there any more standard term?

Comment: I never heard of any term for that. I have some doubt that this condition would be  really significant and that the term "mega-concave" (that is 'very' concave) is suitable.

Comment: I do not know any term, but if you use this a lot, I would rather suggest to call $f$ concave of order $n$ if $x^nf'(x)$ is decreasing, or possibly use some words like "linearly concave", "quadratically concave" etc. (to me that sounds more elegant than "mega-concave", but in the end that is just my subjective opinion)

Comment: $xf'(x) \ge 0 $ or $xf'(x) \le 0 $ for all $x$ is uninteresting if the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R},$ because $f$ must be constant. And if the argument range is not the complete $\mathbb{R}$ then the property is not translation-invariant like the standard definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $x>0$ here. Let $g(t) = f(e^t)$. Since $g'(t)=e^t f'(e^t)$, the property you describe is equivalent to $g$ being concave. In words, one would describe it by saying that *$f$ is a concave function of $\log x$* (since $t=\log x$). There is no shorter term.

Related: the [Hadamard three-circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_three-circle_theorem) is often stated as "$\log M(r)$ is a convex function of $\log r$".

Unrelated: [logarithmically concave functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function), where the logarithm is applied to the function rather than its argument.